# control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

Tags: c

Ok, I have a code in C. Its noughts and crosses.
But i  don't know about my 'sprawdzenie'(check). 
IDE send me control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type].
I have no idea whats wrong but I know my code isn't beauty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char plansza[3][3];
void wczytaj()
 {
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[0][0],plansza[0][1],plansza[0][2]);
printf("-------\n");
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[1][0],plansza[1][1],plansza[1][2]);
printf("-------\n");
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[2][0],plansza[2][1],plansza[2][2]);
}
char sprawdzenie()
{
 if((plansza[0][0]&&plansza[0][1]&&plansza[0][2] =='x' )|| 
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][0]=='x') || 
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][2]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') || 
 (plansza[2][0]&&plansza[2][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') ||
 (plansza[1][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[1][2]=='x') || 
 (plansza[0][1]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][1]=='x') || 
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') || 
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][0]&&plansza[2][0]=='x'))
 {
   return 1;

}else if((plansza[0][0]&&plansza[0][1]&&plansza[0][2]=='o') ||   
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][0]&&plansza[2][0]=='o') || 
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') || 
 (plansza[0][1]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][1]=='o') || 
 (plansza[1][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[1][2]=='o') || 
 (plansza[2][0]&&plansza[2][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') ||  
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][2]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') ||
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][0]=='o'))
  {
    return 2;
}

}
void gracz_x()
{
   unsigned int i=3;
   unsigned int j=3;
   wczytaj();
   printf("Podaj wiersz i kolumnę: ");
   scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    if(plansza[i][j]!='o')
     plansza[i][j]='x';
  else{
    printf("Podaj poprawne współrzędne: ");
    scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    plansza[i][j]='x';
}
}
void gracz_o()
{
    unsigned int i=3;
    unsigned int j=3;
    wczytaj();
    printf("Podaj wiersz i kolumnę: ");
    scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    if(plansza[i][j]!='x')
    plansza[i][j]='o';
else{
    printf("Podaj poprawne współrzędne: ");
    scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    plansza[i][j]='o';
}

 }
 int main()

 {

char wynik=0;
int kolejka = 0;
while(wynik==0)
{
    if(kolejka==0)
    {
        gracz_o();

    }else{
        gracz_x();
    }
    kolejka=kolejka+1;
    wynik=sprawdzenie();
    if(kolejka==9){
        printf("remis");
        break;
    }
}
wczytaj();
if(wynik==1)
{
    printf("wygryw x\n");
}else if(wynik==2)
    {
        printf("wygryw o\n");
    }

return 0;  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that your function `sprawdzenie` is supposed to return `char` but it might not. You have an `if` and an `else if`. If neither of these conditions are met, the function will get to the end and not return anything. This isn't allowed because the function is expected to return `char`.

Add a default return value at the end or add an `else` block to prevent your function from ending without returning anything.

Comment: Ok I will try do it. Thanks so much for answer!